# One instance attribute referencing another, with updates after class instantiation

Tags: python, class, instance-variables

I am looking for best practices on setting one instance attribute that references another instance attribute after the class has been instantiated.

For example:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = self.a + 1
```

```py
>>> obj_foo = Foo()
>>> obj_foo.a
1
>>> obj_foo.b
2
>>> obj_foo.a = 5
>>> obj_foo.a
5
>>> obj_foo.b
2 # I want this to be 6
```

Is this bad practice for one instance attribute to reference another?

I can see how implementing a method to check for and update dependent instance attributes, but this seems like a lot of overhead/hacky. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you don't actually want to store the value of `b` at all, but instead want to generate it based on the value of `a` dynamically. Luckily, there's a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) class/decorator that you can use just for this purpose:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.a + 1
```

This will create a read-only property `b` that will behave just like a normal attribute when you access it as `foo.b`, but will a because it is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). It will re-compute the value based on whatever `foo.a` is set to.

Your fears about calling a method to do the computation every time are not entirely unjustified. Using the `.` operator already performs some fairly expensive lookups, so your toy case is fine as shown above. But you will often run into cases that require something more than just adding 1 to the argument. In that case, you'll want to use something like caching to speed things up. For example, you could make `a` into a settable property. Whenever the value of `a` is updated, you can "invalidate" `b` somehow, like setting a flag, or just assigning `None` to the cached value. Now, your expensive computation only runs when necessary:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self._a = a

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
        self._b = None

    @property
    def b(self):
        if self._b is None:
            # Placeholder for expensive computation here
            self._b = self._a + 1
        return self._b
```

In this example, setting `self.a = a` in `__init__` will trigger the setter for the property `foo.a`, ensuring that the attribute `foo._b` always exists.